# Any builtin function in mysql to sanitise string variables

Tags: mysql, escaping

I have a stored procedure in MySql where the input comes from user. I want to avoid SQL injection.
Is there any function in MySql which does prevent SQL injection, I have googled but most websites show me the php `mysql_real_escape_string` for MySql.

I want to sanitise the input variables at stored procedure level. I have used prepared statements but still is there any builtin function in MySql to sanitise given string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_Xyz` 
(IN _abc varchar(40),
)
BEGIN
   SET @abc = _abc;
   // This might cause sql injection
   SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1 = @abc;
   // We must use prepares statements 
   // But is there any mysql builtin function to sanitize input
   # Say SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1 = PREVENT_SQL_INJECTION(@abc);
   # In PHP we usually do
   # $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
   # mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='{$name}'");
END
```

So since php provided a function, is there any function similar to it in MySql. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should be handling this in your app layer.  I have never heard of escaping queries at the database level (though I'm sure it has been done).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers that you follow these guidlines:

- Just combine variables with your fixed queries in the procedure. The variables cannot cause SQL injection if the queries are not dynamic.
- Use `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` with query parameters if the queries are dynamic. Most of the time this is unnecessary anyway, but if you need to form queries with optional search clauses or optional columns in the select-list for example, you may have to use dynamic SQL.

But to answer your question directly: yes, there is a builtin function in MySQL that sanitizes strings so they can be safely interpolated into dynamic SQL queries *without* using parameters.

[`QUOTE(str)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) returns a quoted string, with special characters escaped.

```
mysql> SELECT QUOTE('Don''t!') as _quoted;
+-----------+
| _quoted   |
+-----------+
| 'Don\'t!' |
+-----------+
```

It's similar to PHP's [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

That said, in 16 years of using MySQL, I have never needed to use this function. It's almost always better to use prepare-and-execute with query parameters.

Comment: +10. Bill correctly (as always) points out the `QUOTE` function. My answer was wrong in this regard. I've never had a need to use the QUOTE function. We don;t need to "escape" values supplied via *bind placeholders* in *prepared statements*.

Comment: NOTE it appears that `QUOTE()` will NOT escape or otherwise sanitize the backtic used in MySQL. If you use dynamic SQL and use backtick for column names or such, this could be a fairly big issue.

Comment: @Zexelon, You should use query parameters.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, from the app side, but when building dynamic SQL the scope is DB server and while you can use prepared statements they have limitations (ex. when trying to pivot data with a dynamic number of columns).

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a good question.  One cannot always trust documentation or even well developed products when it comes to site security.  You perhaps want to keep hackers from exploiting known or newly discovered security holes in PHP, MySQL, or some other system component.  Such are found, exploited, added to bug lists, fixed, and deployed in new releases regularly.

For high throughput applications, where a regular expression match is a speed issue, the correct way to determine if your input string is inserting a backslash before single quotes and properly handling utf-8 or illegal sequences is to try some and watch the string come into MySQL.  This investigative technique may work for you.  (I don't remember how it logs stored procedure I/O.)

1. Execute the following SQL: set global general_log = 'ON';
2. Submit a string with a single quote, some identifiable string like 'Abraham Lincoln', and a wide variety of utf-8 and illegal characters in it.
3. Execute the following SQL: show variables like general_log%;
4. Use some good programmer's tools (egrep and vim on Cygwin, LINUX, UNIX, or Mac) to find 'Abraham Lincoln' and see EXACTLY what MYSQL received for the SELECT.
5. Turn off the heavy logging with: set global general_log = 'OFF';

It is easier with INSERT and UPDATE because you can just use a SELECT to find out what the database stored.

In the event you do not have high volume, regardless what others say, what documentation says, or even what your results are from the logging above, be safe and use a regular expression to validate the reasonableness of all input values coming from the HTTP request.  This is among the security architect's top rules.

There are dozens of ways to validate user strings, but, to be secure, it MUST be done in code that can be modified during simulated browsing.  Client side validation is for user convenience and reduces network bandwidth over other schemes, but it cannot provide security.

Since you are using a stored procedure, it may be convenient to validate it there with a regular expression. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html. I believe that MySQL compiles the pattern so it is fast. You may wish to speed test it by running the HTTP(s) transaction from a JavaScript loop a million times.

Place one of the SELECT statements in the form shown in the above MySQL links in place of "// This might cause sql injection" and test the result. Ensure that you do something intelligent if you get a zero returned, meaning the string is NOT sensible.

It is important that you ANCHOR your regular expression on both sides with the ^ and $ beginning and end anchors respectively.  This example regular expression might be a good one for a phone number: '^[0-9a-zA-Z().-]+$'

You may want to leave your validation range wide in cases like the example above for international phone numbers.

Comment: I always assumed Prep. Statements were 100% safe. Just learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Bill Karwin (correctly) points out the MySQL **`QUOTE()`** function. The first statement in this (my) answer was *wrong*.  I stand by my general line of thought that we don't need to "escape" values that are supplied via placeholders in a prepared statement.

<strike>There's no builtin SQL function to do that. There's no need for one.</strike>

We can use bind placeholders in a prepared statement. For example:

```
  PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1 = ?';
  EXECUTE stmt USING @abc;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

---

In this particular case, there's no need to use a prepared statement. Within a MySQL stored program, we could do this without introducing a SQL Injection vulnerability:

```
  SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1 = @abc ;
```

Given the stored procedure in the question, we wouldn't actually need to use a user defined variable, we could just reference the argument variable without assigning it to an intermediate user-defined variable:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_Xyz`(IN _abc varchar(40))
BEGIN
   -- no SQL Injection vulnerability
   SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1 = _abc;
END$$
```